# Validation of String containing DateTime in a specific pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I'm trying to do some validation to the params that a receive from a post in Nodejs.
The body is something like:

```
{
    "startDateTime": "2019-10-01 00:00:01",
    "endDateTime": "2019-10-01 23:59:59",
    "interval": "00:00:01"
}
```

So, i need to validate if `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` are in the pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`, and `interval` in `"hh:mm:ss"`

I try to use the moment package, but didn't work

```
const testDate = moment(startDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", true).isValid()
```

I'm passing `StartDateTime = "2019-10-01 00:00:01"` and `testDate` is getting assigned to false.

Anyone could help?

Comment: [_“Tokens are case-sensitive.”_](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) The correct format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong Format. Try `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"` instead.

> To learn more about Moment.js Formats, take a look at its [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/).

```js
let response = {
    "startDateTime": "2019-10-01 00:00:01",
    "endDateTime": "2019-10-01 23:59:59",
    "interval": "00:00:01"
};

const testDate = moment(response.startDateTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", true).isValid();

console.log(testDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```